# PostgreSQL NULLable foreign key index optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.2. Two variations of records can be stored in the following table. `alarmConfigurations` entries where `ac_p_id` is NOT NULL can exist more than once, but those where `ac_p_id` is NULL must only exist once (hence the `ac_unique_row_no_port` constraint).

As you can see, regular indexes are created on all other foreign keys, these get scanned a lot. But for `ac_p_id`...

1. Is there any particular advantage to creating the non-unique constraint `ac_index_p_id` with IS NOT NULL (as opposed to not specifying, like the others)?
2. In fact, if I only create `ac_unique_row_no_port`, will that also be used for scans where `ac_p_id` is NOT NULL?

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE alarmConfigurations (
  ac_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ac_ad_code TEXT NOT NULL,
  ac_ad_et_code TEXT NOT NULL,
  ac_e_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ac_as_code TEXT,
  ac_p_id INTEGER,
  ac_details HSTORE,          -- extra configuration
  CONSTRAINT ac_ad_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ac_ad_code, ac_ad_et_code)
    REFERENCES alarmDefinitions (ad_code, ad_et_code)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT ac_as_code_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ac_as_code)
    REFERENCES alarmSeverities (as_code)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT ac_e_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ac_e_id)
    REFERENCES entities (e_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT ac_p_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ac_p_id)
    REFERENCES ports (p_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX ac_index_e_id ON alarmConfigurations(ac_e_id);
CREATE INDEX ac_index_ad_code ON alarmConfigurations(ac_ad_code);
CREATE INDEX ac_index_ad_et_code ON alarmConfigurations(ac_ad_et_code);
CREATE INDEX ac_index_p_id ON alarmConfigurations(ac_p_id)
  WHERE ac_p_id IS NOT NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ac_unique_row_no_port
  ON alarmConfigurations(ac_ad_code, ac_ad_et_code, ac_e_id)
  WHERE ac_p_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any particular advantage to creating the non-unique constraint ac_index_p_id with IS NOT NULL (as opposed to not specifying, like the others)?

Personally, I'd leave the where clause out on that one, in case you ever want to run a query with an arbitrary `where ac_p_id is null or ac_p_id = ?` or some other convoluted expression.

> In fact, if I only create ac_unique_row_no_port, will that also be used for scans where ac_p_id is NOT NULL?

No. It'll only get used if you explicitly specify `ac_p_id is null` in your clauses. The entire `where` clause used in the index must be around in the query for it to be considered. (Give or take minor rewrites that PG deals with, but don't count on them without testing.)